# android OnTouch startActivity results in force close

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, ontouchlistener

I want to make touch screen to intent another layout
I have already make onTouchListener

Here is my code:

```
  package com.example.final_project;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.MotionEvent;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
        setContentView(view);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View to_main, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sort.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return false;
                }

            }
```

even though I try to create another touch.class still close

```
   package com.example.final_project;

import android.content.Context;

import android.graphics.Canvas;

import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class touch extends RelativeLayout {

public touch(Context context) {

        super(context);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

     }

     @Override

     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

         if (getX() != 0 && getY() != 0) {

             canvas.translate(getX(), getY());

         }

         super.onDraw(canvas);

            }
        }
```

Here's sort.class code

```
    package com.example.final_project;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class sort extends Activity {
    Button toMessage;
    Button toBoard;
    Button toMain;
    Intent iMain = getIntent();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toMessage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tomessage);
        toBoard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.toboard);
        toMain = (Button)findViewById(R.id.tomain);

        toMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(sort.this , choose.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        toBoard.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i2 = new Intent(sort.this , board.class);
                startActivity(i2);
            }
        });

        toMain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i3 = new Intent(sort.this , MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i3);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

"I want to make touch screen to intent another layout"  that's just like some of game
start view has"touch here to start" and LogCat show "MainActivity [line: 23] - onTouch(View, MotionEvent)"

Comment: What is the error? post the stack trace

Comment: post your sort.class code also

Comment: Please add LogCat log than only any one can help you out. Mean while what do you mean by "I want to make touch screen to intent another layout" you mean to say you want to show another view or want to open another acitivity named "sort"?

Comment: I have post sort.class on  the top,and I'm not good at use LogCat,so I'm not sure the code is you want......

Comment: did you find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set setContentView for the sort activity try it with adding the following code in your activity file.

```
setContentView(yourview);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,but is every layout needs to add setContentView??

Comment: No need at all. But every activity must have setContentView which able to allow the user to interact with the application. If this is helpful to you, then give your support.